# How to edit individual entries in the DBF Library for Python

Tags: python, database, dbf, dbase

Wondering how I can edit individual values using Ethan Furman's dbf library. I can edit the fields using

```
with dbf.Table(insertPreviouslyAssignedValueHere) as table:
    for record in dbf.Process(table):
        record[field] = desiredValue
```

but this edits an entire column to be the same value. I need a way to edit values anywhere in the file individually as well as add new rows to edit.
I've tried reading over some old documentation [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200813022934/https://pythonhosted.org/dbf/) but I can't find a function for editing individual cells.
I can also peek at an individual value though

```
table[column][row]
```

But still, no editing feature in this fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A record is also a context manager, so:

```
with table[column][row] as rec:
    rec.some_field = 77
```

will work.  The advantage of doing it this way is that if you are updating multiple fields, and one of the assignments raises an exception, the record is not updated and so not in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Interesting solution, thanks. This is a great python package, it's very versatile for dealing with old database files. Is there any chance that the documentation will be available on a live site? It's very useful and I would like others to be able to find it easily as well.
Also, thank you for answering quickly and kindly, most developers aren't open to emails, much less come to your rescue on StackExchange.